# WebDataRocks If I change the tab while downloading the slide, the download is aborted

Tags: typescript, pivot-table, webdatarocks

When converting from pivot table to html in webdatarocks, pending conversion stops when tab changes How do I fix this ? (if you want the code i can add)

I'm opening the table in an iframe maybe that's why I'm not sure

Answer (score 0):

Usually, browsers have lower priority for inactive tabs. This can affect how JavaScript code is executed in this particular case as well.

The simplest solution would be not to switch tabs while export is in progress. As an alternative, you can check other StackOverflow threads with suggestions on dealing with inactive tabs.

Comment: this is wasting me a lot of time, i will probably look for another solution thank you.